# Intersection of height one prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A$ be a commutative, integrally closed, noetherian ring and as $\mathfrak p$ ranges over height one prime ideals, we have:
$$A = \bigcap_\mathfrak p A_{\mathfrak p}.$$

The proof I have seen proceeds so:

It is clear that $A \subset \bigcap_\mathfrak p A_{\mathfrak p}$. For the other way, assume $\phi \in \bigcap_\mathfrak p A_{\mathfrak p}$ and define the ideal:
$$I_\phi = \{x \in A: x\phi \in A\}.$$
Since $\phi \in A_\mathfrak p$, there exists $f,g \in A$ and $g\not\in \mathfrak p$ such that $\phi = f/g$. This implies that $g \in I_\phi$ and therefore $I_\phi$ is not contained in any height one prime ideal which implies that $I_\phi = A$(See Edit).

Therefore, $1 \in I_\phi \iff \phi = \phi.1 \in A$ and this finishes the proof.

My question is: Where were the assumptions that $A$ is noetherian and integrally closed used?

EDIT: I realize now that one cannot conclude that $I_\phi = A$. I would like to know if this proof can be modified to finish it off. However maybe this approach is failed and that would be an acceptable answer too.

Comment: Why does "$I_\phi$ is not contained in any height one prime ideal" imply that $I_\phi=A$?

Comment: Sorry, I realized what i said was wrong.

Comment: How is the proof completed then? The proof I knew was for Dedekind domains. Can the idea be modified or is a new idea necessary?

Comment: @user26857 Thanks, that probably settles the question.

Comment: Yes. You need more tools in order to prove such a result in general.

Comment: A proof can be found here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/031O